# Is it possible to update a sharepoint list when an item is created or modified in excel using microsoft flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, power-automate, excel-online

I am trying to build a flow which will update a sharepoint list when a row is created or modified in excel. I tried the flow as shown below but it step "condition" gives result as false even when there is file present with the name mentioned in the condition. Can anyone suggest what can be the issue. Any kind of assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using the graph explorer to get the file ID and use that in your flow instead of name. 
 https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Hello @HarryB, Thank you for the suggest, it worked! :) but now it is giving me another error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.\r\nclientRequestId:".. I wanted to ask you is there any possibility to get a sharepoint list updated whenever the excel is moditified without using power automate. any alternative way.  Sorry, I am new to all this and not from a technical background. hence, not aware about it.

Comment: If you don’t want to use power automate, I think you will need to seek help from 3rd-party tools cause SharePoint itself doesn’t provide such solutions to sync with Excel spreadsheet. Here I will provide another similar post using Flow, hope it helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-to-Update-Create-Delete-list-in-SharePoint-by-using-excel/td-p/299333

Comment: @Hiranya as Chelsea mentioned, I suggest that you spend some time learning power automate as it is the tool made for the scenarios that you're working with! It will help you a lot!  Regarding Datetime error check the format matches with the locale set for your site collection

Comment: Thank you, Chelsea and Harry. :) Yes, will learning power automate. :)